# How to add an api key to the Credentials of Azure Automation Account?

Tags: api-key, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I want to add an api key for my sendgrid account to Azure Automation account.
I did the search but no luck.
[image]

How should I do this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add your api key in password and set a related username(it does not verify the connection between username and password) like below:

[image]

Usually we use get a credential with [`Get-AutomationPSCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/credentials#get-a-credential-asset) and get its username and password

```
$myCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'MyCredential'
$userName = $myCred.UserName
$securePassword = $myCred.Password
$password = $myCred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

For now, you need only to get the password which is sendgrid api key.